# How to Execute PL/SQL Stored Procedures with Parameters using the EXECUTE keyword

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

The following example creates a stored procedure which finds the minimum value between two numbers and prints out the minimum value:

```
create or replace procedure findMin(x IN number, y IN number) IS
BEGIN
   IF x < y THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(x||' is the smallest number.');
   ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line(y||' is the smallest number.');
   END IF;
END;
```

Executing the procedure inside of an anonymous PL/SQL block creates no problems:

```
begin
findMin(5,10);
end;
```

However, the following code outside of an anonymous block does not work:

```
execute findMin(5,10);
```

How can we execute stored PL/SQL procedures using the execute command when those procedures require parameters? Is this even possible?

Comment: what do you mean,"does not work"? Are you running this in sqlplus?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical phrase. What do you mean by it?

Comment: At least give the error messages or other description of what actually didn't work.  We're not telepathic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "does not work" - here is a screenshot of a brief session (in SQL*Plus) to prove that it works just fine.

Two notes: `execute` is a SQL*Plus command, so it doesn't need to be terminated by semicolon (the semicolon shouldn't hurt anything, but it is just not needed); and, to be able to see the output, you must execute the SQL*Plus command `set serveroutput on` first. If "does not work" simply meant "I don't see the output", then perhaps you missed this step. (It is not shown in my illustration because I set up my system to have server output on by default.)

```
SQL> create or replace procedure findMin(x IN number, y IN number) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3     IF x < y THEN
  4        dbms_output.put_line(x||' is the smallest number.');
  5     ELSE
  6        dbms_output.put_line(y||' is the smallest number.');
  7     END IF;
  8  END;
  9  /

Procedure created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
SQL> execute findMin(5, 10)
5 is the smallest number.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
```